# Function or property for VBR processing speed

Tags: powershell, veeam

I'm using VEEAM Backup & Replication 11, and I'm running a PowerShell script:

```
Get-VBRJob | Where-Object {$_.IsScheduleEnabled -eq "$true" -and $_.GetLastResult() -eq "Success"}
```

This gives me result of success jobs, Now I want to further filter it on the basis of processing speed.
I have tried multiple properties but they don't seem to work .
I added `-and $_.Info.Processing` to get processing speed of the job, but I had no output.

```
& -and $_.GetLastResult().DataProcessingSpeed.
```

Please suggest the function or property that I can include in my script to fetch processing speed too.
Please also mentioned property for getting the DataTransfer speed, which will tell me about the data transfer speed between source VM and target repository.

```
Connect-VBRServer -Server "Backup-server-IP"

#Fetching Success Jobs
$SuccessJobs = Get-VBRJob | Where-Object { $_.IsScheduleEnabled -eq "$true" -and $_.GetLastResult() -eq "Success" -and $_.GetLastResult().DataProcessingSpeed -lt 200}
```

```
Name        MemberType Definition                                                                                                   
----        ---------- ----------                                                                                                   
CompareTo   Method     int CompareTo(System.Object target), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object obj)                            
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                               
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                                            
GetType     Method     type GetType()                                                                                               
GetTypeCode Method     System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()                                    
HasFlag     Method     bool HasFlag(System.Enum flag)                                                                               
ToBoolean   Method     bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                 
ToByte      Method     byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                    
ToChar      Method     char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                    
ToDateTime  Method     datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                            
ToDecimal   Method     decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                              
ToDouble    Method     double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                
ToInt16     Method     int16 IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                  
ToInt32     Method     int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                    
ToInt64     Method     long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                   
ToSByte     Method     sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                  
ToSingle    Method     float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                 
ToString    Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider), string ToString(string...
ToType      Method     System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider)                      
ToUInt16    Method     uint16 IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                
ToUInt32    Method     uint32 IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                
ToUInt64    Method     uint64 IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                
value__     Property   int value__ {get;set;}
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the output from `GetLastResult()` to ensure it contains the expected property? `Get-VBRJob |% GetLastResult |Get-Member` should show you the properties available on the result object

Comment: Yes I have, but I didn't find any property i.e. related to processing speed. Please suggest me how can I get backup speed from my script.

Comment: Well, then you know why your code isn't working :) Share the output from `Get-Member`

Comment: Property name is given as follows: CompareTo, Equals , GetHashCode, GetType, GetTypeCode, HasFlag, HasFlag, ToBoolean, ToByte, ToChar, ToDateTime, ToDecimal, ToDouble, ToInt16, ToInt32, ToInt64, ToSByte, ToSingle, ToString, ToType, ToUInt16, ToUInt32, ToUInt64, value__

Comment: Please [add the details to your existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77757408/edit) :) Make sure you include the full output, including the type name at the top

Comment: Please check again :). I don't think there are any property that will get me speed details.

Comment: You still haven't updated your question. But the property names listed would suggest `GetLastResult()` returns an enum value - it won't contain any additional details

Comment: Yes you are right it gives out either Failed, Success or Running. Please check the question I have added output to it.